# Django filter which may include None

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Is there a way to include None when filtering on a list of values?

```
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(amount=10).count()
9
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(amount=None).count()
30
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(amount__in=[10]).count()
9
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(amount__in=[None, 10]).count()
9
```

I would expect the last call to return 39, rather than 9.

In my actual use case None may or may not be included in the list of values to be filtered on. I could use an if/else block to check for None in the list of values and construct the query using Q objects if needed, but doing so for a large number of filters is going to be a mess. There must be a better way, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you'll need to use Q objects, possibly this way it won't be a mess:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(amount__isnull=True) | Q(amount__in=the_list)).count()
```

and only include that first part if `None` is in the list...

Or something like:

```
query = Q(amount__in=the_list)
if None in the_list:
    query |= Q(amount__isnull=True)

MyModel.objects.filter(query).count()
```

Not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the ```|=``` syntax, so at the very least that will help.

Comment: Is there any explanation why `in` lookup not work for `None` in an iterable?